# Mapping an array in Bootstrap column in Javascript/React

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, underscore.js

This is ultimately what I want to achieve:
[image]

What I see is that `WORK` is rendered on the left hand side, in `col-md-3`. The rest on the right is iterated in `col-md-9`. I'm trying to replicate this design, but am having trouble doing so. Here's what I have:

```
workList(item) {
    return (
        <section>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-xs-3">
                <div className="about-title">
                    <h1>Work</h1>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-xs-9">
                    <div className="about-body">
                        <h3>{item.company}</h3>
                        <h4>{item.position}</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    )
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            {_.chain(this.props.work).map(this.workList).value()} //this.props.work is just a JSON object that contains a list of the places I've worked at
        </div>
    )    
}
```

This results in the following:

[image]

which is pretty obviously wrong because I'm calling `WORK` the same number of times as the length of the JSON object array. My question is - how can I render a list of arrays specifically on the right side with Bootstrap grids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you generate Work and your Items together. You have to seperate them. Since your JSON contains the places you've worked so far, there is no need to generate Work all together with the places.

Here is an example:

```
workList(item) {
    return (
    // generates rows in your col-9 to get the look you wanted
    <div className="row about-body">
      <div className="col-xs-12">
          <h3>{item.company}</h3>
          <h4>{item.position}</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    )
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="container">
              <div className="row">

                // generate left site once
                <div className="col-xs-3 about-title">
                    <h1>Work</h1>
                </div>

              // generate right site once
              <div className="col-xs-9">               
                {_.chain(this.props.work).map(this.workList).value()} //this.props.work is just a JSON object that contains a list of the places I've worked at
              </div>
            </div>           
        </div>
    )    
}
```

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Megajin

**Edit:** posted the right code.

Comment: I've tried that - the first row works because there is a `col-xs-3` on the left side, so the first job description on `col-xs-9` is aligned properly. However, for the second job description, it'll fall under `WORK` and aligns itself to the left because there's no longer a `col-xs-3` there. How do I work around this?

Comment: Did you try my edited code? It was not complete, I am sorry for that.
Now it generates rows in your col-xs-9. That should work.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thank you :)